# How to solve this def function

Tags: python, function, converters

Hi I am new to python I need to write program that does write with def function.

I basically need to that if I write anyting it will convert from small word to big and contrariwise and last is if I write number than it adds  +5 so basically if I write 5 It will show number 10. I dont knwo how to wrtie the last step. I try to convert it to int to get these +5 but it will always show error becaouse other are in string. Here is my code

```
def vyp(a, b):
  
  if a == a.lower(): 
    print(a.upper())
    


  elif a == a.upper():

    print(a.lower())
  
  elif b(int)==a:
    print(b +5)
  
    
a=input("Enter any word or number:")  

c = vyp(a)
```

I try to convert it to int to get these +5 but it will always show error becaouse other are in string

Comment: What do you think `b(int)` does? Also, where does the input `b` come from? You haven't defined it in the script in your question

Comment: By the way, `a.swapcase()` switches each character in `a` between lowercase and uppercase. For example, `'abC'.swapcase()` results in `'ABc'`.

Comment: Also your function expects 2 args but you are only passing 1

Comment: Also, you write `c = vyp(a)`, but `vyp` has no return statement in its definition, so you'll just end up with `c` equal to `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to make sense of what you were thinking with your attempt. However, here is a function that has the behavior you describe.

```
def vyp(a):
    if a.isdigit():
        return str(int(a)+5)
    return a.swapcase()

print(vyp("22"))     # 27
print(vyp("HellO"))  # hELLo
```

Note that this only works as expected for integer (i.e. whole) numbers. If the string entered is `"22.5"`, then 5 is not added.